# Creating objects in javascript from string array

Tags: javascript

Why do I get "Syntax error: missing :after property id" when trying to create an array (**arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues**) using as name for the key a string taken from another array (**arrayTextAreasNames**)?

```
var arrayTextAreasNames = ["name","surname","dob"];
var arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues=[];

for (var i=0; i<arrayTextAreasNames.length; i++) 
{
    arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[i] = 
    {
        arrayTextAreasNames[i]: "text",  //Syntax error: missing :after property id
    };
}
console.log(arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues);
```

Comment: What is your desired output for `arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access array values inside an object directly. You have to use the brackets.

```
var arrayTextAreasNames = ["name","surname","dob"];
var arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues=[];

for (var i=0; i<arrayTextAreasNames.length; i++) 
{
    arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[i] = {};
    arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[arrayTextAreasNames[i]] = "text";
}
console.log(arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable as an object property name. You could try;

```js
var arrayTextAreasNames = ["name","surname","dob"];
var arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues=[];

for (var i=0; i<arrayTextAreasNames.length; i++) 
{
 temp_obj = {};
    temp_obj[ arrayTextAreasNames[i] ] = "text";
    arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues.push(temp_obj);
}
console.log(arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an assignment to name attribute with variable.

```
arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[i] = 
{
    arrayTextAreasNames[i]: "text",  //Syntax error: missing :after property id
};
```

You need to change it to

```
 arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[i][arrayTextAreasNames[i]] = "text";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an object as the result, you can use the following:

```js
var arrayTextAreasNames = ["name", "surname", "dob"];
var values = ['John', 'Smith', '04/03/1954'];
var arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arrayTextAreasNames.length; i++) {
  arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[arrayTextAreasNames[i]] = values[i];
}
console.log(arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues);
```

Results in the following output:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Smith",
  "dob": "04/03/1954"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 enhanced object literals to do this directly:

```
arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues[i] = {
    [arrayTextAreasNames[i]]: "text"
};
```

Or, better yet,

```
arrayTextAreasNamesAndValues = arrayTextAreasNames.map(name => {
    [name]: "text"
});
```